# iPhone wont sync to iMac

Tags: iphone, imac, data-synchronization

Does anyone know why whenever I connect my iPhone XR to my iMac to try to sync new music & playlists from my music library, I get a message saying 'iPhone cannot be synced because the iPhone could not be found on the network'? I have good internet signal & Wi-Fi, so I cannot understand why the Mac won't recognise my iPhone. I've tried restarting the iMac but that hasn't helped. Can anyone suggest a remedy please?

Comment: By 'connect ' do you mean plug in physically, or find on the network?

Comment: I use a cable plugged into phone and iMac, but the screen tells me I can’t sync phone as it’s not connected to the network

Comment: It shouldn't even be looking for it on the network if it's plugged into the Mac's USB, unlocked & has been set to Trust the Mac.